# Adding CSS classes and media to an empty div and append

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to re-create an Instagram like sort of page with some jQuery included. This is for a course I'm taking, so I'm a student basically.

This particular part of the exercise is asking me to:

```
 - Empty the content of a class div.
 - iterate over the media that is given.
 - create an empty div and assign two classes, background image and append to the "empty" class.
```

The code I have so far is the following:

```js
  function renderUserMedia (media) {
    // The class that is being emptied.
    $('.user-media').html('');
     // iteration
    media.forEach(function (mediaItem) {
      // empty div to add to every iterated picture with whatever is needed
      var div = $('<div>').addClass('user-media-item u-pull-left').css('background-image', mediaItem).appendTo('.user-media');
    });
  }
```

All media is fetched through an API which I have no idea how is being configured (school configuration and what not), and the media is from a "dummy" insta page I guess.

What's happening is that images are not happening on the browser, and I think it has something to do with the `.css` implementation of the images iterated. The property *background-image* does not exist in the `css` file, so there might be something going on.

I have also tried to append to `'.user-media'` with `$('.user-media').append(div);` on the next line, but it didn't produce the desired result, which is to have all pictures iterated from `forEach` with the `'.user-media-item'` class.

```
.user-media-item {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Could someone please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `mediaItem` is likely a URL, I suppose? The syntax for `background-image` is not `background-image: SomeUrl`, it is `background-image: url(SomeUrl)`.

Comment: *The property background-image does not exist in the css file* - it doesn't need to be in the *css file* as you're changing the `style` property of the element directly.   ie `.css("prop", "value")` -> `style='prop:value'`

Comment: Can you provide an example of `media`?  (without disclosing any private info ofc)

Comment: Using the correct background-image format as noted by @CBroe - your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ys8o56cj/ (with some full-url paths to images)

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that I had also tried the `url` approach. I wasn't sure if that was actually producing the desired result. This is the code as it stands now:
`var div = $('<div>').addClass('user-media-item u-pull-left').css('background-image', 'url(' + mediaItem + ')').appendTo('.user-media');` Thanks for re-assuring this is the way to make it work @CBroe and @freedomn-m. How would I go about providing an example of the content of the media argument?

Comment: Just in case this adds any info, the `'user-media-item'` and `'u-pull-left'` are already created classes, I'm not supposed to "create" them, just use them. Perhaps here is the problem?¿?¿?

Comment: @CBroe the media is in a local folder, so the URL approach is not really going to work I assume, just double-checked.

Comment: What do you mean by "local folder"? Local _where_?

Comment: Local in my computer, this whole thing is a project folder downloaded from the school for me to "make it work".

Comment: `function renderUserMedia (media) { console.log(media)...` add output to question

Comment: You should be able to use a url to file:\\ to a local file - it will depend on the value of `media` / `mediaItem` - you might need to make changes to the values to get them to work locally. Make sure your mediaItem is in quotes: `.css('background-image', "url('" + mediaItem + "')")`

Comment: @freedomn-m the output is an array of 25 objects with id, username, media_type and caption. Is this what you meant? thanks again!

Comment: Yes - if `mediaItem` is an object with multiple properties, then `"url("+mediaItem+")"` will be `url([object Object])`.   Is any of those properties a url or image blob?  If not, how are you expecting `background-image:username` to work?   A sample of the 25 objects would help.

Comment: In fact yep, one of them is a permalink. I had such small space in my screen due to so many windows open that I didn't realize! here is one of them: `3
: 
{id: '17869088461632086', username: 'user', media_type: 'IMAGE', caption: 'Quick update on our #COVID19 measures:⁣\n⁣\n All o…ashyourhands regularly, #stayhome, and stay safe!', permalink: 'https://www.instagram.com/p/B-EitBboNgM/', …}`

Comment: I can't tell if `permalink` goes to a page or an image (access denied).  But, given this info, you might want:   `.css("background-image", "url('" + mediaItem.permalink + "')")`.  If it's a page then there might be another property if imageLink you could use, or you might have to download that page and parse it... seems a bit over the top for your assignment though.

Comment: I have implemented your solution but still it doesn't output the desired images, so I guess I'll have to move on with the rest of to-do things and get back to this at a later  time. I very much appreciate your help in this! I'll make sure to reply if I end up finding what is going on. Thx again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having checked everything and not being able to retrieve images, the only needed thing was (thanks to @freedomn-m and @CBroe for directions) to include the actual `key` that holds the location of the file. In this case a local folder.

```js
  function renderUserMedia (media) {
    $('.user-media').html('');

    media.forEach(function (mediaItem) {
      var div = $('<div>').addClass('user-media-item u-pull-left').css('background-image', 'url(' + mediaItem.media_url + ')').appendTo('.user-media');
    });
  }
```

In case of using the url `key`, then we should change to `.css('background-image', 'url(' + mediaItem.permalink + ')')` as it was showing in the object containing the info of the images.